# xpages extension library deployment in domino server

Tags: web, xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, xpages-extlib

I deployed the XPages Extension library on my domino server 8.5.3 by following these steps :

1 / Download and unzip the openntf library on the server.

2 / Create an update site and import the site.xml on the server.Everything is imported, enabled and signed with the server id.

3 / In notes.ini , add the following line: = OSGI_HTTP_DYNAMIC_BUNDLES UPDATESITE.NSF  (my update site)

4 / I restarted the server and got this message :nsf based plugins are being installed in the osgi runtime

5 / Check the two libraries to use in XPages application in the application properties in the library extension XPages app demo .

I still have a display like this the extension library is not recognized although it works well when the application is on my local machine (I installed the extension library also in my local machine).
Is what I missed a step in my deployment ?

[image: Xpages displayed]

This is what i have for the tell http osgi ss com.ibm.xsp.extlib command.

[image]

Comment: It would be useful to see some diagnostics, just to rule out a version issue. On the server console, issue the command "tell http osgi ss com.ibm.xsp.extlib". Please paste a screenshot of the resulting output into the question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I posted the screenshot.

Comment: That confirms the server is running a compatible version of ExtLib and the libraries have been called by the application (ACTIVE rather than INSTALLED or <<LAZY>>). It seems like the theme isn't loading the correct stylesheets (they are not ExtLib-specific). The theme should be "OneUI V2.1" (xsp.theme=oneuiv2.1 in xsp.properties) or one of its colour variants. The files for any later version wouldn't exist on the server though.

Comment: Agree with Paul: extlib is running and being used by the application. Otherwise you would be seeing an error 500.

Comment: indeed , the theme in xsp.theme is oneuiv2.1 . Even if I change it in any color , the result does not change.

Comment: The oneui theme works fine. But the oneuiv2.1 doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the relevant theme files may not be installed on your server for some reason. Here is a page outlining the theme files and their locations for various Domino versions https://wiki.openntf.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=7110658

Comment: Thank you.Effectively, i didn't find the oneuiv2.1 in my themes directory. I copied it from my local machine to the server but alawys the same result.

Comment: It works now, i didn't copied the entire file. Thank you very much.

Comment: Re-running the Domino installer should also add any missing files, I think, though I haven't tried it.